# Proof that a mapping onto $[0,1]$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let each $(A_i,T_i) = (\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$ and define $\phi : \prod (A_i, T_i) \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\phi (<a_1, a_2, ...>) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}}$.

In order to show that this is continuous, let $a =<a_1, ...> \in \prod (A_i, T_i)$ be arbitrary and $V \in T_{[0,1]}$ be arbitrary.  Then I need to find a $U$ open in $ \prod (A_i, T_i)$ such that $a \in U \land f(U) \subseteq V$.

If I let $V =$ the open interval $(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} - \epsilon, \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} + \epsilon)$, I figure I could let $U = \{a_1\} \times \{a_2\} \times ...\{a_n\} \times A_{n+1} \times ...$, but from here I can't figure out a way to show that $\phi(U) \subseteq V$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It suffices to show that $\phi^{-1}(a 2^{-n},(a+1)2^{-n})$ is open whenever $a, n$ are integers with $0\leq a<2^n$ and $n\geq 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\rangle\in U$, so that $x_k=a_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\varphi(x)-\varphi(a)\right|&=\left|\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{2^{k+1}}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{x_k}{2^{k+1}}\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{a_k}{2^{k+1}}-\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{x_k}{2^{k+1}}\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{a_k-x_k}{2^{k+1}}\right|\\
&\le\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{|a_k-x_k|}{2^{k+1}}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step uses the triangle inequality for absolute values.

- What are the possible values of $|a_k-x_k|$? What is the largest of them?
- If $|a_k-x_k|$ had the largest possible value for every $k\ge n+1$, what would $\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{|a_k-x_k|}{2^{k+1}}$ be?
- How can you choose $n$ to make that maximum possible sum less than a given positive $\epsilon$?

Comment: If by $<x_1, x_2, ...> \in V$ you mean a sequence, then $a_k = 0$ or $2$, and $x_k \in V$.  So there will not be a maximum value because $a_k = 0$ and $x_k \in V \subseteq [0,1]$.  So $x_k \lt \sum \frac{a_k}{2^{k+1}} + \epsilon$.  I feel like I may have misinterpreted something here though.

Comment: @Oliver: No, $x_k$ is *not* an element of $V$. The elements of $V$ are infinite sequences of $0$s and $2$s, so each $x_k$ is either $0$ or $2$.

Comment: I see, I was using $V$ as the open set in $[0,1]$.  Then the maximum difference is $2$, and the sum given the largest possible value would $=(\frac{1}{2})^n$ because of summation and geometric series, and choose $n > \frac{-ln(\epsilon)}{ln(2)}$.  But this gives me the difference between $a_n$ and $x_n$, I'm not sure how I'd apply this for just $a_n$.

Comment: @Oliver: Sorry about the $V$: I inadvertently interchanged your $U$ and $V$. I’ve corrected it to $U$. \\ $U$ is an open nbhd of $a$. You’d like to choose it small enough so that $\varphi[U]\subseteq V$. This means choosing it so that for each $x\in U$ we have $\varphi(x)\in\big(\varphi(a)-\epsilon,\varphi(a)+\epsilon\big)$, i.e., so that $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(a)|<\epsilon$.